# In Javascript why, console.log(0 && 0 === 0); returns 0 instead of true?

Tags: javascript, comparison

The following example returns **0**:

```
console.log(0 && 0 === 0);
```

The following example returns **true**:

```
console.log(2 && 2 === 2);
```

Comment: Did you mean to run `(0 && 0) === 0` instead? That `2 && true` returns `true` is expected, as is the result of `0 && true`.

Comment: `A && B` returns the value `A` if `A` can be coerced into false; otherwise, it returns `B` (taken from https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-and-and-or-operators-in-javascript ). `0` can be coerced to `false`, so you are getting back the value of A which is `0`.